# Looking for a manga where FL is betrayed by her brother, i think?

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

In this manga I believe it was her brother who told her to lie about what powers she had to everyone so they all saw her as useless. He then marries her off to the ML but whilst she is on her way their he orders for her to be killed. She goes back in time realises that he never cares for her and changes everything by telling everyone about her powers and helping her people. She still looks to get married to the ML however.
I have no idea what the name of this manga is. I think that she is a princess but I am not sure

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: I think it was blonde

Answer (score 2):

Is it "*My Sweet Enemy, Thy Name is Husband*"? It pretty much matches your description.

The fl is blonde and so is her brother. She has some powers but only uses them in her 2nd life ig.
On the day of her marriage, she dies in her carriage and finds out that her brother was behind it. The ml takes revenge on her whole family.